# Rails merge with empty relation is returning records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to understand why the `merge` is adding more records instead of filtering the previous collection:

```
(byebug) ::Reporting::Entry.where(reporting_report_id: []).count
0
(byebug) ::Reporting::Entry.where(reporting_report_id: []).merge(report.entries).count
2
```

The actual behaviour of the `merge` should be to intersect. It is working correctly in this example:

```
(byebug) Reporting::Entry.none.merge(Reporting::Entry.all)
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Here are the sql queries generated by my code:

```
(byebug) ::Reporting::Entry.where(reporting_report_id: []).to_sql
"SELECT \"reporting_entries\".* FROM \"reporting_entries\" WHERE 1=0"

(byebug) ::Reporting::Entry.where(reporting_report_id: []).merge(report.entries).to_sql
"SELECT \"reporting_entries\".* FROM \"reporting_entries\" WHERE \"reporting_entries\".\"type\" IN ('Reporting::IUE::ReportSection') AND \"reporting_entries\".\"reporting_report_id\" = 'df08179e-3ee9-47a5-89b4-17016d340db5' ORDER BY \"reporting_entries\".\"position\" ASC"
```

The policy is defined as:

If you look at the sql generated on the second query vs the first one, the `merge` part is causing the `WHERE 1=0"` to go away. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that "ActiveRecord fails to correctly merge scopes containing IN constraints on the same column."

There is an open issue on the rails repo. People are arguing about how it should behave but it hasn't gotten enough attention yet.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33501

I changed my scope from:

`::Reporting::Entry.where(reporting_report_id: []).merge(report.entries)`

to:

`::Reporting::Entry.where(reporting_report_id: []).where(report: report.entries)`

and now it works as I intended, although merge should have done it.